# bootstrap v4 input group button and textbox alignment issue in IE

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have issue with IE when I use input group with bootstrap v4, works well in chrome. I a m using **IE 11**

This is my plunkr

[input group bootstrap v4](http://jsfiddle.net/26ZM4/256/)

chrome look:

[image]

IE look:

[image]

what I found is form-control has padding: .375rem .75rem;

```
.form-control {
display: block;
width: 100%;
padding: .375rem .75rem;
font-size: 1rem;
line-height: 1.5;
color: #55595c;
background-color: #fff;
background-image: none;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
border-radius: .25rem;}
```

If I increase bottom padding it adjusts well in IE but it mess up in chrome.

So I am looking for solution which should work everywhere.

Thanks

Comment: I don't have an answer but perhaps it's reassuring (or not) that Bootstrap's own input groups on their own pages are also breaking up in IE ;) http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/input-group/

Comment: You may need to fix using css Even bootstrap demo is not working for button addons, http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/input-group/#button-addons

Comment: So is media query a good option? or should I try to find different css, which works for all the cases.

Answer (score 0):

We may use the Internet Explorer media queries. Because according to the browser some values have changed.

```
/***for IE browser***/
@media screen and (min-width:0\0) {
    .form-control {
        padding: 9px 10px;
    }
}
```

FYR:
http://jsfiddle.net/iyyappan13391/26ZM4/257/